# Show that operator is symmetric and positive

Tags: functional-analysis

My operator is defined as

$$ A[u] = \frac{d^2}{dx^2}[a(x)\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}]+b(x)u $$

where
$$\Omega=(0,L), a(x)>0,b(x)>0,\forall x \in \Omega$$
$$u(0)=u(L)=0,\frac{du}{dx}(0)=\frac{du}{dx}(L)=0$$

I use $L_2$ inner product for showing symmetry and positive defining

My attempt to show symmetry $\langle Au,v \rangle=\langle u,Av \rangle$
$$\langle Au,v \rangle=\int_{\Omega}Au*vd\Omega= \int_{0}^L(\frac{d^2}{dx^2}[a(x)\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}]+b(x)u)vdx= \int_{0}^L(\frac{d^2}{dx^2}[a(x)\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}])vdx+\int_0^L(b(x)uv)dx$$

so it is clear now that I should take first part by parts until I get to the right side of symmetry equation
So
$$\int_{0}^L(\frac{d^2}{dx^2}[a(x)\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}])vdx=(\frac{d}{dx}[a(x)\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}])v|_0^L-\int_{0}^L(\frac{d}{dx}[a(x)\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}])\frac{dv}{dx}dx$$

What should I do with the term $\frac{d}{dx}[a(x)\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}])v|_0^L $ because I don't have conditions on $v$

Also I'm stuck how to show positiveness of the operator

P.S. Okay according to the commentaries I showed that operator is symmetric.Thanks a lot. But how to show that it is positive defined?

Comment: You do have conditions on $v$ -- it should be in the domain of $A$, so it satisfies the boundary conditions you wrote down (for $u$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you apply the boundary conditions on $v$ you can inegrate by parts a second time to get
$$ \langle Au , v\rangle = \Bigg[ \frac{d}{dx}\Big( a(x) \frac{d^2u}{dx^2}\Big) v\Bigg]_0^L-\Bigg[a(x) \frac{d^2u}{dx^2} \frac{dv}{dx}\Bigg]_0^L + \int_0^L a(x) \frac{d^2u}{dx^2}\frac{d^2v}{dx^2}~dx$$
The first two terms vanish because $v(0)=v(L)=v'(0)=v'(L) = 0$ and you are left only with the last term which is symmetrical in $u$ and $v$.

To see also that the $A$ is positive definite, set $v=u$ and we have
$$\langle Au , u\rangle = \int_0^L a(x) \Big( \frac{d^2u}{dx^2}\Big)^2 ~dx.$$
Now, $a(x) > 0$ and if $(u''(x))^2 \geqslant 0$ throughout the interval, so the inner product is certainly non-negative.  To show it is strictly positive, you need to be sure that $u''(x)>0$ on some non-null set.  One easy route to this is to require $u \in \mathscr C^2(0,L)$ so that $u''$ is continuous.  Then, because not identically zero, $(u'')^2$ must be strictly positive on some small closed interval $I$, and so bounded below by $\varepsilon >0$ on that interval (by continuity) and
$$ \int_0^L a(x) \big( u''(x)\big )^2 ~ dx \geqslant \int_I a(x) \big( u''(x)\big )^2 ~ dx \geq \int_I a(x) \varepsilon ~dx > 0.$$
The final strict inequality follows because the integral is non-negative and if it was equal to zero, then $a(x)$ would be zero (almost everywhere), which is not the case.